# Updating date to present if null or empty php

Tags: php, mysql, date, jquery-jtable

I'm trying to set the date using PHP's `date('Y-m-d')` if the variable is empty or null. The variable is delivered from a `Jquery-Jtable edit form`. Then I have an elaborate if statement which checks if the variable is empty or null:

```
if ( !isset($data['date_closed']) || strlen($data['date_closed']) == 0 
     || !$data['date_closed'] || $data['date_closed'] == "0000-00-00" 
     || $data['date_closed'] == NULL || is_null($data['date_closed']) 
     || empty($data['date_closed']) ) {
            $date['date_closed'] = date('Y-m-d');
}
```

I have desperately added every check that I could find to make it work but it hasn't. The final value getting stored in the DB is `000-00-00`. Just the to make sure that my changes were being registered I typed just this line:

```
$date['date_closed'] = date('Y-m-d');
```

and the date got updated to the DB as today's date.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: basic debugging - did you do a `var_dump($data['date_closed'])` to see if that code is actually working correctly? Did you look at the final SQl statement to make sure it's built correctly?

Comment: I tired that but I got a error which says "Error in communicating to server" so I'm not sure why that isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(isset($data['date_closed'])) {
    $parsed_date = strtotime($data['date_closed']);
    if($parsed_date === false) {
        $data['date_closed'] = date('Y-m-d');
    } else {
        $data['date_closed'] = date('Y-m-d', $parsed_date);
    }
} else {
    $data['date_closed'] = date('Y-m-d');
}
```

If $data['date_closed'] is set and is in a format recognized by PHP it will reformat it to Y-m-d format otherwise it will set to current date in Y-m-d format